# How to hide toolbar inside collapsing toolbar layout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Implemented flexible space with image pattern using collapsing toolbar layout. I am encountering issue that toolbar whatsoever be state of collapsing toolbar layout remains pinned static on top.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/event_management_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.butterflyinnovations.collpoll.postmanagement.share.event.eventManagement.EventManagementActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/event_management_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/event_management_collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/event_management_collapsing_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/default_content_description"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:src="@color/blue"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/event_management_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Attaching the screenshot: The added screenshot is design of the xml aaded above
[Attached Screenshot of added XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQVQc.png)

Gone through various codes and tutorial. Yet unable to find exact cause of worry.

**Update**

Using following class as listener :

```
public abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

public enum State {
    EXPANDED,
    COLLAPSED,
    IDLE
}

private State mCurrentState = State.IDLE;

@Override
public final void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        if (mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.EXPANDED;
    } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
        if (mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.COLLAPSED;
    } else {
        if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.IDLE;
    }
}

public abstract void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state);
```

}

and maipulating as follows:

```
 activityEventManagementBinding.eventManagementAppbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object : AppBarStateChangeListener() {
        override fun onStateChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout, state: AppBarStateChangeListener.State) {
            if (state == State.COLLAPSED) {
                supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@EventManagementActivity, R.color.primary_color))
            } else {
                supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@EventManagementActivity, R.color.caldroid_transparent))
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Remove attribute `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` from `Toolbar`.

Comment: Hi @JeelVankhede removed the attribute and tried but still default case is toolbar remains visible and once scrolled it hides. Is there any thing I need to do with style. The desired result is at start the toolbar should be transparent and when layout scrolled on collapse toolbar should be visible with primary color.

Comment: Hi @JeelVankhede I am implementing AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener and manipulating scrolls to set toolbar transperent and primary color on basis of state collapsed or expanded. I guess this is just a hack helping me and believe there might be some cleaner elegant way.